# Modifying a jPanel using buttons on another jPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I've just approached Java and I'm working on a project for my University class.
I'm working on a Milionaire game but I'm stuck.

I've got a JFrame class in which I have 2 panels. The first one is made of buttons, the second one is the panel I want to change by pressing the buttons. Buttons have their own class with their constructor and the same is for the panels cause they have a different layout. I need to create a method in the button class to remove the second panel from the frame and add a third panel (described in another more JPanel class). So I technically need to acess from button class method to my JFrame class constructor. Is there a way to do it?

I've got my first Panel class and my Button class with its ClickListener method.
Now I need to know how can i modify my JFrame class in my Button method to close the first Panel at click, opening in the same position another one.

Button Method

```
public class ClickListenerD1 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        buttonPressed();
    }

    private void buttonPressed()
    {
        JPanel panel3 = new Domanda1();
    }
}
```

Main JFrame class

```
package nuovaPartita;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * Visualizza la finestra di gioco.
 */
public class NuovaPartitaViewer extends JFrame
{
    private static final int FRAME_LUNGH = 1600;
    private static final int FRAME_ALT = 900; 

    JPanel panel1 = new NuovaPartitaComp1();
    JPanel panel2 = new Start();
    /**
     * Costruisce una finestra di gioco su cui vengono visualizzati due 
pannelli.
     */
    public NuovaPartitaViewer()
    {
        setSize(FRAME_LUNGH, FRAME_ALT);
        setTitle("CHI VUOL ESSER MILIONARIO?");
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);

        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add(panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "_I need to create a new JPanel with a Button click from another Panel to substitute it..._" Can you please describe it a bit more? Seems unclear.

Comment: Yeah sure! I'm sorry first time using stackoverflow.
I've got a JFrame class in which I have 2 panels. The first one is made of buttons, the second one is the panel I want to change by pressing the buttons.
Buttons have their own class with their constructor and the same is for the panels cause they have a different layout.
I need to create a method in the button class to remove the second panel from the frame and add a third panel (described in another more JPanel class).
So I technically need to acess from button class method to my JFrame class constructor.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can implement your listeners inside your JFrame you then have access to the jFrame and all its content

Comment: You can also keep the reference to your panels inside the buttons.

Comment: Maybe take a look at anonymous classes (or even lambdas with functional interfaces) to see how you can add the actionPerformed stuff to your panel class

Comment: Always make edits to the question. Don't post additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the panel corresponding to a button in the button's action listener.

[image]

```
public class NuovaPartitaViewer extends JFrame {

    public NuovaPartitaViewer() {
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(new JLabel("Panel 1"));
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add(new JLabel("Panel 2"));
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.add(new JLabel("Panel 3"));
        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        p4.add(new JLabel("Panel 4"));

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        b1.addActionListener(e -> setPanel(p1));
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        b2.addActionListener(e -> setPanel(p2));
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        b3.addActionListener(e -> setPanel(p3));
        JButton b4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        b4.addActionListener(e -> setPanel(p4));

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        buttonsPanel.add(b1);
        buttonsPanel.add(b2);
        buttonsPanel.add(b3);
        buttonsPanel.add(b4);

        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setTitle("CHI VUOL ESSER MILIONARIO?");
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setPanel(JPanel p) {
        add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        revalidate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new NuovaPartitaViewer());
    }
}
```

If all your buttons are customized (`extends JButton`) then you can add the action listener code directly in that class. Pass the corresponding `JPanel` in the constructor so you can use it in the action listener.

Additionally:

- Don't set the size of the frame, use `pack()` instead.
- Call `setVisible(true)` as the last thing you do in the method.